# AngularJS infinite scroll, not working only with chrome fullscreen

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs, scroll

I am doing an infinite scroll on a ng-repeat, changing the limitTo value with a loadMore() function.

Here is the code :

Directive (found on a jsfiddle) :

```
angular.module('scroll', []).directive('whenScrolled', function() {
    return function(scope, elm, attr) {
        var raw = elm[0];

        elm.bind('scroll', function() {
            if (raw.scrollTop + raw.offsetHeight >= raw.scrollHeight) {
                scope.$apply(attr.whenScrolled);
            }
        });
    };
});
```

Here is the code into the controller :

```
var nb = 15;
$rootScope.vue = nb;
$rootScope.loadMore = function() {
    $rootScope.vue = $rootScope.vue + 5;
}
```

Here is the code into the html :

```
<div class="container-fluid" id="full-2">

    <div class="row" id="full-3">
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-10" id="fixed" when-scrolled="loadMore()">
            <ul>
                <li ng-repeat="pg in eleves0 | search:query:['millesime']:operator | orderBy:orderProp | limitTo:vue">

                [...]

                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
```

And here the css :

```
html, body{
    background-color:#ccc;
    height:100%;
}

#full{
    height:100%;
}

#full-1{
    height:90%;
}

#full-2{
    height:100%;
}

#full-3{
    height:100%;
}

#fixed{
    height:100%;
    overflow: auto;
}
```

This code works perfectly on IE, Firefox, Opera. When i scroll down, new content appears

It doesn't work's on Chrome with full screen.
It works on Chrome, sometimes, if the window's height is < ~300-500 px (depends on the computer)

do you know where it could come from ? how to resolve it ?

Comment: Do you still have the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Just found a solution.
change to :

```
#fixed{
height:100%;
overflow: scroll;
```

}

It works

Comment: Add some explanation with answer for how this answer help OP in fixing current issue

Comment: The scroll event is sent to an element when the user scrolls to a different place in the element. It applies to window objects, but also to scrollable frames and elements with the overflow CSS property set to scroll (or auto when the element's explicit height or width is less than the height or width of its contents).

Comment: @ Gullfaxi171 Issue fixed or not?

Comment: @user3364329 Where to place this CSS give a complete solution.